# submitting binary to apple and geting CFBundleVersion error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, svn

We are trying to submit a new binary version with in-app purchase into the Apple iphone app store. However, we are getting the following error when trying to do so:

"The key CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of positive integers."

We believe that the problem is that svn is appending an 'r' for the revision # to the app. How do we compile our binary so that the letter 'r' is removed from the version?

Comment: Do you have a build action doing that for you? (changing the info.plist file for you)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the \r is indeed the problem, set the `svn:eol-style` property  to `LF` on all files (see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) Possibly various svn clients are configurable to set it as an automatic property based on filenames.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting a problem with the svn number being less than what the previous version. This is because when we started coding our new version, we used a new repository. 
How do I tell svn to set the version number to one higher? do you know? Am googling it and not finding the answer easily.

Comment: Is that some requirement of Apple? I would totally suspect you can just up numbers not related to subversion as long as you keep it consistent. The only way I know to add to the number is by committing something, anything.

Comment: Yeah. That's what we had to end up doing. Around 230 times ... :)
But it all worked out in the end. App is submitted(!)